# What unobvious conditions can dictate how long getchar has access to newline characters after input is provided?

Tags: c, scope, stdin, getchar

I have two functions both of which take input from using getchar.

`Example1()` is intended to gather input and return the value. However, when called twice in a row this function registers the newline character submitted from the previous call to `getchar`. This doesn't make sense to me because I would have thought that `getchar` would be limited to the actual scope of *where* it was called, ending when the function itself ends.

```
int Example1()
{
    printf("Gather input from example1\n");

    int user_input;
    while ((user_input = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        return user_input;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`Example2()` gathers input storing it in a newly created struct member. When called twice this function doesn't produce the same issue that the first function does.

```
struct foo *Example2()
{

    struct foo *user= (struct foo*) malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    
    printf("Gather input from example2\n");

    int user_input
    while ((user_input = getchar()) != '\n') 
    { 
        user->user_input= user_input;
    }
    
    return user;
}
```

I thought that when the function returns the actual buffer for `getchar` would be gone with the scope of that function call. What would cause the newline character to be kept in the `stdin` buffer in the `Example1()` function, but not in the `Example2()` function?

Full Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct foo {
    char user_input;
};

struct foo *Example2()
{

    struct foo *user= (struct foo*) malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    
    printf("Gather input from example2\n");

    int user_input;
    while ((user_input = getchar()) != '\n') 
    { 
        user->user_input= user_input;
    }
    
    return user;
}

int Example1()
{
    printf("Gather input from example1\n");

    int user_input;
    while ((user_input = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        return user_input;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct foo *user = Example2();
    printf("Example 2 function user_input 1/2 : %d\n", user->user_input);
    
    struct foo *user2 = Example2();
    printf("Example 2 function user_input 2/2 : %d\n", user2->user_input);

    printf("Example 1 function user_input 1/2 : %d\n", Example1());
    printf("Example 1 function user_input 2/2 : %d\n", Example1());
}
```

Comment: By the way, why are you printing `user->user_input` twice instead of using `user2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar()` reads **one character** from the buffer. The buffer is dependent of function scopes.

In your `Example1` function, `return` statement is executed after `getchar()` is called once (regardless of whether the character read is newline or not).
Therefore, only one character is read by one call of `Example1` and it may be only part of a line. If `Example1` read only part of a line, the left part of line will be read by subsequent calls of `getchar()` (or other stdin-reading functions).

On the other hand, in your `Example2` function, there are no `return` statement in the loop and `getchar()` is executed until newline character is read. (even if EOF is reached!) Therefore, `Example2` will read until end of one line by one call.

Answer (score 1):

In the first function you don't have a loop because you are `return`ing in its body, so at most you are reading one character. It reduces to an `if`.

The functions aren't equivalent by any means and the differences are unrelated to scopes or using a `struct foo`. Further, the state of the standard input stream (consumed by `getchar()`) is global to the program.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. If a while loop is used like this does it actually get optimized at the compile level to an IF?